# indexing in numpy nd-array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy nd array with the following shape as an example:

```
import numpy as np

# Note this can be variable and have different dimensions each time
shape = [100, 100, 100, 5]
array = np.zeros(shape)
```

Now what I want to do is address the last dimension, so I need something like:

```
array[:, :, :, i] = something
```

But I cannot hard code it like this as the dimensions can change depending on the input. So is there a way to index the last dimension of an nd-array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup:

```
array[..., i] = something
```

That's a literal `...` there, not a placeholder for something else you're expected to write.

Comment: did not know about this one, thanks.  Also nice to know that `array[...,i,:]`, and `array[i,...]` work as expected.  If one had a large array (many dimensions), would there be a way to get at the nth index or nth to last index other than stacking `:`s at one end?

Comment: @Dan: The easiest way I know of would be to create a view of the array with the desired axis moved to the front using [`numpy.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html), then index the new view. For example, to access index k in the nth axis, we'd use `numpy.rollaxis(array, n)[k]`.